# Handling API http return errors on JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, jqxhr

I have this html page:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  $.ajax({
    url: "https://api.github.com/users/Microsoft/",
    type: 'GET',
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function(res) {
      $('#result').text(JSON.stringify(res, null, '\n'));
    }.error: function(jqXHR, error, errorThrown) {
      if (jqXHR.status && jqXHR.status == 400) {
        alert(jqXHR.responseText);
      } else {
        alert("Something went wrong");
      }
    }
  });

})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <pre id="result" style="color:red"></pre>
</div>
```

If Take away this:

```
.error: function(jqXHR,error, errorThrown) {  
           if(jqXHR.status&&jqXHR.status==400){
               alert(jqXHR.responseText); 
           }else{
               alert("Something went wrong");
           }
```

The result is shown properly, right now, it doesn't show anything. Just a blank page.

What I want, is to handle some http error that could happen if the API response isn't successful.

Any ideas?

Comment: You made a typo. `key: value` pairs in object literals are separated by commas (`,`) not periods (`.`). You put a period  between success and error. Voting to close due to typo)

Comment: Created a snippet. Ran the snippet. Error immediately visible. Press F12 in your page and you will see it there too

Comment: _This question was caused by a problem that can no longer be reproduced or a simple typographical error. While similar questions may be on-topic here, this one was resolved in a manner unlikely to help future readers. This can often be avoided by identifying and closely inspecting the shortest program necessary to reproduce the problem before posting._

Comment: Even after fixing the error mentioned by @Quentin, nothing will show because you haven't told it to show anything. If you get an error, all you're doing is `alert`ing, so nothing goes into `#result`...

Comment: It's a typo. `}.error` instead of `}, error`

Comment: And after that, if you do not alert but instead do a `console.log("Something went wrong",jqXHR.status);` you will see you get a 404

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Typo where you define `error` method:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

  $.ajax({
    url: "https://api.github.com/users/Microsoft/",
    type: 'GET',
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function(res) {
      $('#result').text(JSON.stringify(res, null, '\n'));
    },
    error: function(jqXHR, error, errorThrown) {
      if (jqXHR.status && jqXHR.status == 400) {
        alert(jqXHR.responseText);
      } else {
        alert("Something went wrong");
      }
    }
  });

})
```

Comment: Simple typos shouldn't be answered. There is  a close vote reason for them. The comments already identify the typo and several others have already added their vote to close the question

Comment: Upvotes on an answer to typo question also prevents the OP from simply deleting the question, which they should do because the question has no long term value